Signal store rxMethod not concluding when running component tests
I have an rxMethod which I call on the onInit hook inside the signal store.
// session.store.ts
// rxMethod that does session polling

startSessionPolling: rxMethod<void>(() => {
  return timer(0, HALF_HOUR_POLLING)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => 
        service.getSession().pipe(tap(session => patchState(state, { hasAccess: true }) ))))
    }
)

// triggered in onInit hook

withHooks({
  onInit({ startSessionPolling }) {
    startSessionPolling()
  }
})

Now inside my login.component.spect.ts, I'm mocking the service.getSession() and returning a mockValue, but it never reaches the pipe(tap(session => ...)).
it('should set hasAccess to true', () => {
  const spy = spyOn(authService, 'getSession').and.returnValue(of(mockSession));

  fixture.detectChanges();
  
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // Called 0 times
  expect(component.hasAccess()).toBe(true); // False
});

Now I'm not completely sure it should work since I'm new to these SignalStores. But in my component I inject the store, and check for the store.hasAccess() signal.
Haven't found many examples testing these signal-stores, rxMethods, so I'm kinda just experimenting.
Any ideas ?
